# A column in my dataframe does not seem to correspond to the input List (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe, indexing

I want to assign one of the columns of my dataframe to a list. I used the code below.

```
listone = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['m', 'g'], ['h'], ['y', 't', 'r']]
df['Letter combinations'] = listone
```

The 'Letter Combinations' column in the dataframe doesn't correspond to the list, instead seems to assign random elements to each row in the column. I was wondering if this method indexes the elements differently causing a change in the order or if there is something wrong with my code. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Here is my complete code

```
listone = [[a, b, c], [m, g], [h], [y, t, r]]
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
my_matrix  = {'Numbers': numbers}
sample = pd.DataFrame(my_matrix)
sample['Letter combinations'] = listone
sample
```

My output looks like:

````
```
````

`Numbers    Letter combination`
`0  1                  [b]`
`1  2                  [m, g]`
`2  3                  []`
`3  4                  [r]`

````
```
````

Comment: Can you show your output? It looks fine for me when I try it.

Comment: Can you share some code which you tried?

Comment: Please supply a Minimal Complete Verifiable example ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `listone` to be a series. Ie:

```
sample['Letter combinations'] = pd.Series(listone)

sample
   Numbers Letter combinations
0        1           [a, b, c]
1        2              [m, g]
2        3                 [h]
3        4           [y, t, r]
```